# Accumulating array elements in postgres v9.6+

Tags: postgresql

Using postgres SQL v 9.6, have a table containing Integer Arrays (all with same dimensions).
I need to accumulate the values by each element of the array across rows.

ie table with rows of

```
{1,2,3}

{4,5,6}

{7,8,9}
```

to obtain

```
{12,15,18}
```

Tried to use `array_agg()` but its giving a different result

```
SELECT array_agg(array_column) AS "array_accum" FROM mytable;
```

gives

`{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}`

Can this be done easily?

Answer (score 0):

If the array is short, as in your example, I would recommend just summing the individual elements and sticking it back into another array. example:

```
SELECT 
ARRAY[ SUM(array_column[1]) 
     , SUM(array_column[2])
     , SUM(array_column[3])]
FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

A generalized solution:

```
select string_to_array(string_agg(sl,','),',')::integer[]
from (
      select s, (sum(v)::text) sl
        from (
              select s   
                   , array_column[s] v
                from (select generate_subscripts(array_column, 1) as s
                           , array_column 
                        from array_list
                     ) al
             ) sv
       group by s
       order by s ) sal;
```